# Is there a way I can retrieve users that are repeated on a table, with have a certain value on a column?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm sorry if the title isn't easy to understand, I was having trouble condensing the issue on the title.
I have a table that lists users who have access to a page, and what kind of user they are.

Table has email(which serves as username), name, user type on the page they have access to, and the code for the page itself. So if a user has access to more than one page, they exist multiple times with the kind of access they have on each page.

Example:

```
| email              | first name        |user type | page code |
| --------           | --------------    | -------- | -----     |
| First@email.com    | First             | Admin    | page1     |
| Second@email.com   | Second            | Admin    | page1     |
| Second@email.com   | Second            | Admin    | page2     |
| Third@email.com    | Third             | User     | page3     |
| Fourth@email.com   | Fourth            | Admin    | page1     |
| Fourth@email.com   | Fourth            | User     | page2     |
```

What I want to do is get the email and first name for those users that are admins (or superusers) on both page1 and page2. so in this example second would be included, but none of the others since they only have admin access to one, the other or none.

In the end I'd like to have the list without emails repeating.

The logic I'm following and have right now is this:

```
select * from users
where (usertype = 'Admin' or usertype= 'Super')
and (page_code= 'page1' or page_code= 'page2')
```

This gets me the emails with access to either one of them, so now I'm thinking I need to filter those into those that "are true" both with page code page1 and page2 condensing them into a single registry but if I use an and clause:

```
select * from users
where (usertype = 'Admin' or usertype= 'Super')
and (page_code= 'page1' and page_code= 'page2')
```

I get no results.

I'm thinking another option could be creating a query (or virtual table for each page and using a join with the email address? I'm not sure how the syntax for that would go though.

```
select * from users
where (usertype = 'Admin' or usertype= 'Super')
and page_code= 'page1'
--this would give me users with admin/super access to page 1
------------------------------
select * from users
where (usertype = 'Admin' or usertype= 'Super')
and page_code= 'page2'
--this would give me users with admin/super access to page 2

--todo: Something to select emails, and first name from records that exist on both?
```

if a join would work, is that the "right" way to do it? or is there a better way practice-wise?

Sorry if I'm rambling, I feel like I'm either really close or completely missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this do?

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (email, first_name, user_type, page_code) as
  2    (select 'first@email.com' , 'first' , 'admin', 'page1' from dual union all
  3     select 'second@email.com', 'second', 'admin', 'page1' from dual union all
  4     select 'second@email.com', 'second', 'admin', 'page2' from dual union all
  5     select 'third@email.com' , 'third' , 'user' , 'page3' from dual union all
  6     select 'fourth@email.com', 'fourth', 'admin', 'page1' from dual union all
  7     select 'fourth@email.com', 'fourth', 'user' , 'page2' from dual
  8    )
```

Query begins here:

```
  9  select email, first_name
 10  from test
 11  where user_type = 'admin'
 12  group by email, first_name
 13  having min(page_code) = 'page1'
 14     and max(page_code) = 'page2'
 15     and count(distinct page_code) = 2;

EMAIL            FIRST_
---------------- ------
second@email.com second

SQL>
```

Comment: I will test it tomorrow, I’m not sure what min, max and count are doing here but I’ll do some research and check it out. I’ll update with my results.

Comment: COUNT says that there can be just two distinct PAGE_CODE values; if MIN is PAGE1 and MAX is PAGE2, then that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I see. I have tested it for a larger table, but for some reason it only returns one of the registries that fulfill the condition, when there should be 9. I am comparing it to a solution I'm currently testing using a join on two queries.